# length zero error

Tags: r, function

I am getting an argument of length zero after running the function. I have looked at other users with this problem, but I can't figure out the error.

```
x<-1
p_atk<-0
p_def<-0
war<-function(n_atk, n_def){
  d_atk<-sort(g(n_atk), decreasing = T)
  d_def<-sort(g(n_def), decreasing = T)
while(x<=n_atk & x<=n_def){
ca<-n_atk - x
cd<-n_def - x
a<-(sort(d_atk)[ca])
d<-(sort(d_def)[cd])

if (a>d) {p_def<-p_def+1}
  else {p_atk<-p_atk+1}

x<-x+1
  }

 Saldo<-paste("ataque perde", p_atk, ";", "defesa perde", p_def)
  res<-dados(n_atk, n_def)
  print(res)
  return(Saldo)

}
```

When I use the function `war`, the following message appears:

> Error in if (A > D) { : argument is of length zero

Comment: One problem is that you can't have "x<-1   p_atk<-0   p_def<-0  " all on one line (try it outside the function and you'll see the error). If you're having trouble writing a function, a good approach is to write it with some sample data outside of a function, and then once you have that working edit it a little and wrap it in a function.

Comment: I think you might want a `paste` rather than a `c` here: `Saldo<-c("ataque perde", p_atk, ";", "defesa perde", p_def)`